# Flutter : Unexpected character when Hit API

Tags: flutter

I Got Error error catch FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
ServiceApi.login

function that called login service

```
login(username, password) async {
        final session = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        Map<String, dynamic> data = {"username": username, "password": password};
        final ret = await ServiceApi().login(data);
        print('return $ret');
}
```

this is my service login

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> login(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
            Map<String, dynamic> jsonString;
            dynamic uri = Uri.parse('${UrlApi.api}/login');
            try {
              http.Response res =
                  await http.post(uri, body: jsonEncode(data), headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "*/*",
          });
    
          if (res.statusCode == 200) {
            jsonString = json.decode(res.body);
            print(jsonString);
            return jsonString;
          } else {
            jsonString = json.decode(res.body);
            print("error login $jsonString");
            return jsonString;
          }
        } catch (e) {
          print('error catch $e');
          throw e;
        }
      }
```

Comment: do you happen to know in which line you are getting the error?

Comment: @h8moss idk only `error catch FormatException: Unexpected character`. thrown error on try catch. i run flutter on my device and connect with local api  "wifi connection"

Comment: I think it is possible that the request's response is not valid JSON, could you print `res.body`? Also I recommend you use a debugger to figure out in which line the error is happening